# Duplicate and update rows based on length of list in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and  I would like to duplicate and update rows based on the contents and length of a list that exist in the same row.

```
| Column A     | Column B        | Column c |
| --------     | --------------- | -------  |
| xxxx xxx xx  | ['a', 'b', 'c'] | a        |
| zzz zz zzzz  | ['d', 'e']      | d        |
| aa aaa aaa a | ['f']           | f        |
```

The desired output should look something like this:

```
| Column A     | Column B        | Column c |
| --------     | --------------- | -------  |
| xxxx xxx xx  | ['a', 'b', 'c'] | a        |
| zzz zz zzzz  | ['d', 'e']      | d        |
| aa aaa aaa a | ['f']           | f        |
| xxxx xxx xx  | ['a', 'b', 'c'] | b        |
| xxxx xxx xx  | ['a', 'b', 'c'] | c        |
| zzz zz zzzz  | ['d', 'e']      | e        |
```

The number of elements in Column B will dictate how many times each row is duplicated (if a list has three elements, it will be duplicated twice, if it has 5, it will be duplicated 4 times, if it has one elements, it will not be duplicated etc.) and update Column C with the value in the list at each position.

I have a solution that is manual but would like to see a solution that can accommodate a larger dataset.

Thanks!

Comment: looks like `df.explode('B')` is very close to your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the new rows is not *important*, you can try this one :

```
out = (
    (tmp:=df.explode("Column B"))
        .assign(**{"Column B": df["Column B"], "Column C": tmp["Column B"]})
        # .reset_index(drop=True) # uncomment if needed
)
```

​
Ouptut :

```
print(out)

       Column A   Column B Column C
0   xxxx xxx xx  [a, b, c]        a
0   xxxx xxx xx  [a, b, c]        b
0   xxxx xxx xx  [a, b, c]        c
1   zzz zz zzzz     [d, e]        d
1   zzz zz zzzz     [d, e]        e
2  aa aaa aaa a        [f]        f
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat):

```
n = [len(x) for x in df['Column B']]

pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, n, axis=0), columns = df.columns)
```

Output:

```
       Column A   Column B Column C
0  xxxx xxx xx   [a, b, c]        a
1  xxxx xxx xx   [a, b, c]        a
2  xxxx xxx xx   [a, b, c]        a
3   zzz zz zzzz     [d, e]        d
4   zzz zz zzzz     [d, e]        d
5  aa aaa aaa a        [f]        f
```